# How to split the pyspark dataframe based on the content of the line

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to split the file according to the first character of the line in Pyspark DataFrame.

The original data has a column, the data includes

1. the file name (such as 'DATE20191009')
2. the file content (such as '1', '2', '3')

**Input Sample File(Pyspark DataFrame):**

```
column1

Date20191009

1

2

3

Date20191010

1

4

5
```

I want to get a Pyspark DataFrame with the file name as a split of the data.

The file name is placed in the column1 of the DataFrame, and the contents of the file are placed in the column2 of the DataFrame.

**Expected Output(Pyspark DataFrame)**

```
column1  column2
Date20191009 [1,2,3]
Date20191010 [1,4,5]
```

I tried the **Pandas Dataframe** and **Pyspark DataFrame.collect()**, but both failed due to excessive data volume (more than 9 million rows).

Comment: Please provide information of split such which value you will consider for column 1 and which for column 2 and what you mean by first occurrence

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I described my problem in more detail.

Comment: thanks but I want one more details. Your final name would have any pattern so that I can distinguish it in File Name and File content. For your example I can see file name always have DATE in name and content have numeric value. this is the case please confirm.

Comment: In the original data, the file name begins with DATE plus a specific date, and the file content is Chinese, where I replace it with a NUMBER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> w = Window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

   #Input DataFrame

>>> df.show()
+------------+
|     column1|
+------------+
|Date20191009|
|           1|
|           2|
|           3|
|Date20191010|
|           1|
|           4|
|           5|
+------------+

>>> df1 = df.withColumn('tmp', when(df.column1.startswith('Date'), df.column1).otherwise(None)).withColumn('temp', last('tmp', True).over(w)).drop('tmp')
>>> df1.show()

+------------+------------+
|     column1|        temp|
+------------+------------+
|Date20191009|Date20191009|
|           1|Date20191009|
|           2|Date20191009|
|           3|Date20191009|
|Date20191010|Date20191010|
|           1|Date20191010|
|           4|Date20191010|
|           5|Date20191010|
+------------+------------+

>>> df1.filter(df1.column1 != df1.temp).groupBy(df1.temp).agg(concat_ws(',',collect_list(df1.column1)).alias('column2')).withColumnRenamed("temp", "column1").show()

+------------+-------+
|     column1|column2|
+------------+-------+
|Date20191009|  1,2,3|
|Date20191010|  1,4,5|
+------------+-------+
```